# How to create a new list in Python based on two factors?

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda, key

I have a list of list in Python like this:

```
vehicle_list = [['car', '123464', '4322445'],   ['car', '64346', '643267'], ['bicycle', '1357', '78543'], 
        ['bicycle', '75325', '75425'], ['car', '8652', '652466'], ['taxi', '653367', '63226'], 
        ['taxi', '96544', '22267'], ['taxi', '86542222', '54433'],     
        ['motorcycle', '675422', '56312'], ['motorcycle', '53225', '88885'], ['motorcycle', '773345', '9977'], 
        ['motorcycle', '3466', '987444'], ['truck', '2455554', '5225544'], ['truck', '2455554', '344543'], 
        ['train', '6543355', '6336']]
```

I want to return the top 3 vehicles which has the highest number at the end. Like this:

```
top_vehicle = [['truck', '2455554', '5225544'], ['car', '123464', '4322445'], ['motorcycle', '3466', '987444']]
```

I have tried sorting this way, but with my result, the vehicles are repeating which I do not want. I want the unique vehicles in my sorted list. I have tried the code this way:

```
top_vehicle = (sorted(vehicle_list, key=lambda x: int(x[-1]), reverse = True))[:3]
print(top_vehicle)


[['truck', '2455554', '5225544'], ['car', '123464', '4322445'], ['car', '8652', '652466']]
```

Comment: "Sorting" means changing the order of the elements in a list; it does not involve removing elements of the list.

Comment: @ScottHunter I have edited the question. I wanted a new list which has highest number in the end but also the vehicles are not repeating. I hope I made it clear.

Comment: try to break it down into steps: first you need the best vehicle in each category, then from that list of best vehicles take the top 3

Comment: You need to replace the numbers with actual numbers first. `'12345'` is a string. `12345` is an int. When you try to find the "maximum" elements you will get unexpected results if you use strings instead of ints. Strings are compared in lexicographical order, character by character, so for instance `'100'` is considered smaller than `'22'` because it begins with a `'1'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method by

- Get the item with largest number at end of item for vehicle
- Reverse sort the values of dictionary by the number at end of item
- Get the first three items

```py
vehicle_list = [['car', '123464', '4322445'],   ['car', '64346', '643267'], ['bicycle', '1357', '78543'],
        ['bicycle', '75325', '75425'], ['car', '8652', '652466'], ['taxi', '653367', '63226'],
        ['taxi', '96544', '22267'], ['taxi', '86542222', '54433'],
        ['motorcycle', '675422', '56312'], ['motorcycle', '53225', '88885'], ['motorcycle', '773345', '9977'],
        ['motorcycle', '3466', '987444'], ['truck', '2455554', '5225544'], ['truck', '2455554', '344543'],
        ['train', '6543355', '6336']]

# Get largest one for each vehicle by dictionary
largest = {}
for item, no1, no2 in vehicle_list:
    if (item in largest and int(largest[item][2]) < int(no2)) or (item not in largest):
        largest[item] = [item, no1, no2]

# Reverse sort list by 3rd value and get first three
top_vehicle = sorted(list(largest.values()), key=lambda x:int(x[2]), reverse=True)[:3]

print(top_vehicle)
# [['truck', '2455554', '5225544'], ['car', '123464', '4322445'], ['motorcycle', '3466', '987444']]
```

Answer (score 0):

- Group by vehicle type using a `dict`;
- Select the maximum element of each vehicle type;
- Take the top 3 elements from that list of maximum elements.

To take the top three elements, you can sort like you did, or use [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest).

```py
from heapq import nlargest
from operator import itemgetter

vehicle_list = [['car', '123464', '4322445'],   ['car', '64346', '643267'], ['bicycle', '1357', '78543'], 
        ['bicycle', '75325', '75425'], ['car', '8652', '652466'], ['taxi', '653367', '63226'], 
        ['taxi', '96544', '22267'], ['taxi', '86542222', '54433'],     
        ['motorcycle', '675422', '56312'], ['motorcycle', '53225', '88885'], ['motorcycle', '773345', '9977'], 
        ['motorcycle', '3466', '987444'], ['truck', '2455554', '5225544'], ['truck', '2455554', '344543'], 
        ['train', '6543355', '6336']]

grouped = {}
for v,x,y in vehicle_list:
    grouped.setdefault(v, []).append((v,int(x),int(y)))
# {'car': [('car', 123464, 4322445), ('car', 64346, 643267), ('car', 8652, 652466)],
#  'bicycle': [('bicycle', 1357, 78543), ('bicycle', 75325, 75425)],
#  'taxi': [('taxi', 653367, 63226), ('taxi', 96544, 22267), ('taxi', 86542222, 54433)],
#  'motorcycle': [('motorcycle', 675422, 56312), ('motorcycle', 53225, 88885), ('motorcycle', 773345, 9977), ('motorcycle', 3466, 987444)],
#  'truck': [('truck', 2455554, 5225544), ('truck', 2455554, 344543)],
#  'train': [('train', 6543355, 6336)]}


max_vehicles = [max(l, key=itemgetter(2)) for l in grouped.values()]
# [('car', 123464, 4322445), ('bicycle', 1357, 78543), ('taxi', 653367, 63226), ('motorcycle', 3466, 987444), ('truck', 2455554, 5225544), ('train', 6543355, 6336)]

top3 = nlargest(3, max_vehicles, key=itemgetter(2))
# [('truck', 2455554, 5225544), ('car', 123464, 4322445), ('motorcycle', 3466, 987444)]
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have a list of sorted vehicles, you can loop through it. You only append the vehicle tuple to the `top_vehicles` list if the type of vehicle has not been added before

```py
sorted_vehicles = sorted(vehicle_list, key=lambda x: int(x[-1]), reverse=True)

unique = set()
top_vehicles = []
for vehicle_type, _, number in sorted_vehicles:
  if (vehicle_type in unique): # if the type of vehicle has already been seen
    continue

  unique.add(vehicle_type) # if it has not been seen, add it to the list of seen vehicle types
  top_vehicles.append([vehicle_type, _, number]) # add it to the list of top_vehicles

  if (len(unique) == 3): # get only the top 3
    break

print(top_vehicles)
# [['truck', '2455554', '5225544'], ['car', '123464', '4322445'], ['motorcycle', '3466', '987444']]
```

I noticed that the output of my program does not match yours, but I think the motorcycle one in yours is incorrect because 987444 > 88885.